# Heap memory increasing in each page load in chrome

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am [getting aw snap or sometimes not enough memory problem when I reload my WebGL page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfYEkVdn2IQ). I have a WebGL project which is empty (just a camera + light), developed in unity3d. I am reloading it, and profile its memory.
[image]

As you can see that its load 1.2MB in the first load than 1281 MB in second then 1574 then 2160 and then get crash. I am amazed that why it is happening?

I searched and [found](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/BenVinson/20170501/297195/Unity_WebGL_Memory_Optimization_Part_Deux.php) that

Comment: Which build option do you use? WebAssembly or asm.js?

Comment: I am using web assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of Unity fellows [told](https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-excessive-memory-consumption-1-5gb.622720/#post-4363831) that when browser `Dev Tool` is open, each page reload will increment the memory:
"

> One point to note is that when profiling memory usage on page reloads
>   in Firefox, make sure to have the Firefox web console (and debugger)
>   window closed. Firefox has a behavior that if web console is open, it
>   keeps the Firefox JS debugger alive, which pins all visited pages to
>   be cached in memory, never reclaiming them. Closing the Firefox web
>   page console allows freeing the old pages from memory

**BUT**

My testing suggests that it is true for **Chrome** but **not for firefox**. Firefox keeps increments the memory with each page reload no matter your Dev tools are open or close.

But my problem resolve in chrome (still question on firefox? I guess it the default behaviour of browser), after closing the dev tools memory is not incremented on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**the problem**

the webgl build runs fine on every desktop browser and firefox mobile, but crashes after 3 seconds when using chrome mobile or safari mobile with the "aw, snap" page.

the problem was the amount of RAM that the project was using for loading assets.
i found that the main problem was loading the audio system.

when the game started the RAM usage quickly escalated from 300 MB to 1,3GB.

**how i fixed**

i had a background music 20 minutes long, i cut that to 5 minutes.
click the music, then click override for webgl
set the load type to Streaming
set the quality to 1

with this workaround the RAM usage floats around 600 MB, this allows the build to run on mobile.

[this is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6gML.png)

**EDIT**

turns out that after ios 15.5 update everything runs fine.